# Navigating to screen in another navigator in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

I'm using the new `React Navigation 5` in my React Native app.

The main menu is handled by the `RootNavigator` which is a `Drawer`. The login/sign up are handled by `AuthNavigation` which is a `Stack`.

I'm trying to send user to `Home` screen under `RootNavigator` after a successful login. In other words, I'm trying to send user to a screen under another navigator by issuing `navigation.navigate('RootNavigator', {screen: 'Home'});` but I'm getting an error that reads:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"RootNavigator"} was not
>   handled by any navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'RootNavigator'?

This is what my `App.js` looks like:

```
const App = () => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticatedUser, setIsAuthenticatedUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect( () => {

    // Check for valid auth_token here
    // If we have valid token, isLoading is set to FALSE and isAuthenticatedUser is set to TRUE
  });

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PaperProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {
            isLoading
            ? <SplashScreen />
            : isAuthenticatedUser ? <RootNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />
          }
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

And here's my `AuthNavigator` which is a `Stack`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Components
import Login from '../../login/Login';

const AuthStack = new createStackNavigator();

export const AuthNavigator = () => {
    return(
        <AuthStack.Navigator>
            <AuthStack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={Login} />
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

And here's the `RootNavigator` which is a `Drawer`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

// Components
import Dashboard from '../../home/Dashboard';
import DrawerContent from './DrawerContent';
import ToDoList from '../../active_lists/to_do_lists/ToDoList';

const MainMenuDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const RootNavigator = () => {

  return (
    <MainMenuDrawer.Navigator drawerContent={(navigation) => <DrawerContent navigation={navigation} />}>
      <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={Dashboard} />
      <MainMenuDrawer.Screen name="To Do List" component={ToDoList} />
    </MainMenuDrawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I want to use the cleanest approach for handling this.

Comment: Have you tried calling from the child component this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()) ? I know that you should have a parent navigator (Stack) if you want to navigate from one nested navigator to annother. There must be a big parent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. You're doing `navigation.navigate('RootNavigator', {screen: 'Home'});`, which means navigate to `Home` screen in a navigator nested inside `RootNavigator` screen. but there's no screen named `RootNavigator`, you have a component named `RootNavigator`, but `navigate` expects a screen name.

Looking at your code, you don't have nested navigators, both navigators are still at the root, just rendered conditionally. So you'd usually do `navigation.navigate('Home')` for navigation.

Examples of how nesting works and how the structure looks when you nest: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

2. When you are conditionally defining screens/navigators, React Navigation will take care of rendering correct screens automatically after you change the condition. You don't do `navigate` in this case.

From the auth flow docs:

> It's important to note that when using such a setup, you **don't need to navigate** to the `Home` screen manually by calling `navigation.navigate('Home')`. React Navigation will automatically navigate to the `Home` screen when `isSignedIn` becomes `true`.

Auth flow docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#how-it-will-work

So what you need to do, is change the `isAuthenticatedUser` state in your component. You can follow the guide in the docs for an example using React context, but if you're using Redux, move this state to Redux, or any other state management library you use.

And lastly, remove the `navigation.navigate` after successful login, since it'll happen automatically when you update your condition.